# How to upload multiple image fields in a registration form

Tags: php

Good day, How can I please add two more image fields on my registration form without interrupting with the php code

here is the index.php of the registration form

```
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
        
        <form class="shadow w-450 p-3" 
              action="php/signup.php" 
              method="post"
              enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <h4 class="display-4  fs-1">Create Account</h4><br>
            <?php if(isset($_GET['error'])){ ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
              <?php echo $_GET['error']; ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if(isset($_GET['success'])){ ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
              <?php echo $_GET['success']; ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" 
                   class="form-control"
                   name="fname"
                   value="<?php echo (isset($_GET['fname']))?$_GET['fname']:"" ?>">
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">User name</label>
            <input type="text" 
                   class="form-control"
                   name="uname"
                   value="<?php echo (isset($_GET['uname']))?$_GET['uname']:"" ?>">
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Password</label>
            <input type="password" 
                   class="form-control"
                   name="pass">
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Image Field</label>
            <input type="file" 
                   class="form-control"
                   name="pp">
          </div>
          
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
          <a href="login.php" class="link-secondary">Login</a>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Here is the php that is supposed to upload it to the database>>

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['fname']) && 
   isset($_POST['uname']) &&  
   isset($_POST['pass'])){

    include "../db_conn.php";

    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $uname = $_POST['uname'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    $data = "fname=".$fname."&uname=".$uname;
    
    if (empty($fname)) {
        $em = "Full name is required";
        header("Location: ../index.php?error=$em&$data");
        exit;
    }else if(empty($uname)){
        $em = "User name is required";
        header("Location: ../index.php?error=$em&$data");
        exit;
    }else if(empty($pass)){
        $em = "Password is required";
        header("Location: ../index.php?error=$em&$data");
        exit;
    }else {
      // hashing the password
      $pass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

      if (isset($_FILES['pp']['name']) AND !empty($_FILES['pp']['name'])) {
         
         
         $img_name = $_FILES['pp']['name'];
         $tmp_name = $_FILES['pp']['tmp_name'];
         $error = $_FILES['pp']['error'];
         
         if($error === 0){
            $img_ex = pathinfo($img_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $img_ex_to_lc = strtolower($img_ex);

            $allowed_exs = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
            if(in_array($img_ex_to_lc, $allowed_exs)){
               $new_img_name = uniqid($uname, true).'.'.$img_ex_to_lc;
               $img_upload_path = '../upload/'.$new_img_name;
               move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $img_upload_path);

               // Insert into Database
               $sql = "INSERT INTO users(fname, username, password, pp) 
                 VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
               $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
               $stmt->execute([$fname, $uname, $pass, $new_img_name]);

               header("Location: ../index.php?success=Your account has been created successfully");
                exit;
            }else {
               $em = "You can't upload files of this type";
               header("Location: ../index.php?error=$em&$data");
               exit;
            }
         }else {
            $em = "unknown error occurred!";
            header("Location: ../index.php?error=$em&$data");
            exit;
         }

        
      }else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users(fname, username, password) 
                VALUES(?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([$fname, $uname, $pass]);

        header("Location: ../index.php?success=Your account has been created successfully");
        exit;
      }
    }


}else {
    header("Location: ../index.php?error=error");
    exit;
}
```

I need to add two more additional attach image Fields as I did here

```
<body>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
        
        <form class="shadow w-450 p-3" 
              action="php/signup.php" 
              method="post"
              enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <h4 class="display-4  fs-1">Create Account</h4><br>
            <?php if(isset($_GET['error'])){ ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
              <?php echo $_GET['error']; ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if(isset($_GET['success'])){ ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
              <?php echo $_GET['success']; ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" 
                   class="form-control"
                   name="fname"
                   value="<?php echo (isset($_GET['fname']))?$_GET['fname']:"" ?>">
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">ID Number</label>
            <input type="text" 
                   class="form-control"
                   name="uname"
                   value="<?php echo (isset($_GET['uname']))?$_GET['uname']:"" ?>">
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Password</label>
            <input type="password" 
                   class="form-control"
                   name="pass">
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Image Field</label>
            <input type="file" 
                   class="form-control"
                   name="pp">
          </div>
          

          <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Image Field 1</label>
            <input type="file" 
                   class="form-control"
                   name="pp1">
          </div>



          <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Image Field 2</label>
            <input type="file" 
                   class="form-control"
                   name="pp2">
          </div>



          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
          <a href="login.php" class="link-secondary">Login</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my edited php code so far and its already giving me errors

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['fname']) && 
   isset($_POST['uname']) &&  
   isset($_POST['pass'])){

    include "../db_conn.php";

    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $uname = $_POST['uname'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    $data = "fname=".$fname."&uname=".$uname;
    
    if (empty($fname)) {
        $em = "Full name is required";
        header("Location: ../index.php?error=$em&$data");
        exit;
    }else if(empty($uname)){
        $em = "ID Number is required";
        header("Location: ../index.php?error=$em&$data");
        exit;
    }else if(empty($pass)){
        $em = "Password is required";
        header("Location: ../index.php?error=$em&$data");
        exit;
    }else {
      // hashing the password
      $pass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

      if (isset($_FILES['pp']['name']) AND !empty($_FILES['pp']['name'])) {
         
         
         $img_name = $_FILES['pp']['name'];
         $tmp_name = $_FILES['pp']['tmp_name'];
         $error = $_FILES['pp']['error'];


         $img_name1 = $_FILES['pp1']['name'];
         $tmp_name1 = $_FILES['pp1']['tmp_name'];
         $error1 = $_FILES['pp1']['error'];


         $img_name1 = $_FILES['pp2']['name'];
         $tmp_name1 = $_FILES['pp2']['tmp_name'];
         $error1 = $_FILES['pp2']['error'];

         
         if($error === 0){

            $img_ex = pathinfo($img_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $img_ex_to_lc = strtolower($img_ex);

            $allowed_exs = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
            if(in_array($img_ex_to_lc, $allowed_exs)){
               $new_img_name = uniqid($uname, true).'.Front';
               $new_img_name1 = uniqid($uname, true).'.Back';
               $new_img_name2 = uniqid($uname, true).'.Certified';

               $img_upload_path = '../upload/'.$new_img_name;
               $img_upload_path1 = '../upload/'.$new_img_name1;
               $img_upload_path2 = '../upload/'.$new_img_name2;

               move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $img_upload_path);
               move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $img_upload_path1);
               move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $img_upload_path1);

               // Insert into Database
               $sql = "INSERT INTO users(fname, username, password, pp,pp1,pp2) 
                 VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
               $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
               $stmt->execute([$fname, $uname, $pass, $new_img_name, $new_img_name1, $new_img_name2]);

               header("Location: ../index.php?success=Your account has been created successfully");
                exit;
            }else {
               $em = "You can't upload files of this type";
               header("Location: ../index.php?error=$em&$data");
               exit;
            }
         }else {
            $em = "unknown error occurred!";
            header("Location: ../index.php?error=$em&$data");
            exit;
         }

        
      }else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users(fname, username, password) 
                VALUES(?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([$fname, $uname, $pass]);

        header("Location: ../index.php?success=Your account has been created successfully");
        exit;
      }
    }


}else {
    header("Location: ../index.php?error=error");
    exit;
}
```

1st Image field name is pp in my database

2nd image field name is pp1

3rd is pp2

Comment: What errors would those be, then? Give us a clue please.

Comment: P.S. `move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $img_upload_path1);
               move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $img_upload_path1);` on the second line there I expect it should be `$img_upload_path2` instead of `$img_upload_path1` being repeated.

Comment: `INSERT INTO users(fname, username, password, pp,pp1,pp2) 
                 VALUES(?,?,?,?)`.... there are 4 `?`s here but when you execute it, you are passing 6 parameter values! The lesson here from these two things seems to be to double-check your work more carefully.

Comment: `if($error === 0){`...that's good, but you forgot to check for `$error1` and `$error2` now as well. The code is incomplete.

Comment: Likewise, `$img_ex = pathinfo($img_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` and `if(in_array($img_ex_to_lc, $allowed_exs)){` is only validating the first image name. Are users allowed to upload anything they like for the other two, or did you again forget to validate those?